# PHP Warning: pack(): Type h: illegal hex digit - line 37

Tags: php, pack

Hi everyone i'm trying to make a script that can encode & decode FSK Frequency-shift keying

the problem i'm have so far is PHP Warning:  pack(): Type h: illegal hex digit - line 37

here is my code

```
$RATE = 44100;
$maxVol = pow(2,15)-1.0;
$data = "";

for ($x=0; $x<=$RATE*3; $x++){


    $vv = $maxVol*sin(2*pi()*$x*500/$RATE); #500Hz
    $data+=pack('h',$vv);  #this is line 37

}

echo $data;
```

pack in php seems like it does not support negative number & floats
can someone please help me figure this out

Comment: What's the value of $vv when you get the warning?

Comment: the value of $vv is -1.6694871264829E-8

Answer (score 2):

The `h` format code specifies input as a hex string. It's hard to tell this from the error, but the `-` between the words `digit` and `line` is literally the character that is causing the error (i.e. it's not a separator in the message).

```
PHP Warning: pack(): Type h: illegal hex digit - line 37
                                               ^
```

In other words, your input is interpreted as a string containing the `-` character, which is not a legal hex digit (`0123456789abcdef`).

It's hard to give any specific advice on solving your problem without more information. At the very least, you need to review PHP's implementation of `pack`.